# mediawiki standard install did not generate a localsettings.php

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I did a successful install of media wiki, but when I look to the root directory holding index.php I don't see localsettings.php

Where can I find this file? The [documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aLocalSettings.php) says that the default values are in includes/defaultsettings.php but I don't see that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you did something wrong in the installation. I would go ahead and try to install it a second time.